Как заблокировать в Android TextEdit клавишу Backspace?
Использую следующий код:
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                doSomething();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

Но когда нажимаю клавишу Backspace на физической клавиатуре, символы в TextEdit всё равно удаляются. Строка return true; не блокирует эту клавишу. Как заблокировать в TextEdit клавишу Backspace?
Для тестирования создал новый проект, добавил в него EditText и вышеприведённый код. Никакого постороннего кода нет.
Заметил такой момент: При подключении внешней клавиатуры к телефону сначала несколько секунд работает корректно (Backspace блокируется), но потом появляется уведомление «Выберите метод ввода» (значок в виде клавиатуры) и возникает эта проблема. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что тогда можно сделать, чтобы это уведомление не появлялось?

Delete и Backspace вроде бы разные клавиши.

В Android Delete называется KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL, а Backspace — KEYCODE_DEL.
